# How to "merge" two classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, discord, twitch, python-class

So I'm trying to connect Discord with Twitch chat. So I've got all the components ready and Discord part almost done. When I wanted to start with Twitch, I noticed a problem.

I was planning on using the TwitchIO Python library which requires me to authenticate like this:

```py
from twitchio.ext import commands


class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise our Bot with our access token, prefix and a list of channels to join on boot...
        super().__init__(token='ACCESS_TOKEN', prefix='?', initial_channels=['...'])
```

But I'm already using a Class for the Discord login:

```py
class FTCBot(commands.Bot):
    smart_plug: SmartPlug

    def __init__(self,
                 smart_plug: SmartPlug,
                 intents: discord.Intents,
                 description: str,
                 command_prefix: Union[str, Callable]):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=command_prefix,
                         description=description,
                         intents=intents)

        self.smart_plug = smart_plug
```

PS: `commands.Bot` in the 2 instances are different. Both packages have the same *variable*.

So my Python knowledge is insufficient and I don't know how to log in and access both. Please help.

Comment: You cant really merge classes, but you also dont have to. This is about (Inheritance)[https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp] as 
 `commands.Bot` is the parent of both. I assume the easiest way would be to copy everything you need from the `Bot` class into you own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need to merge the two classes. What I would suggest is while you are doing your imports naming one of the imports differently.

For example

you have

```
from twitchio.ext import commands

class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise our Bot with our access token, prefix and a list of channels to join on boot...
        super().__init__(token='ACCESS_TOKEN', prefix='?', initial_channels=['...'])
```

You could change this to

```
from twitchio.ext import commands as twitchcommands

class Bot(twitchcommands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise our Bot with our access token, prefix and a list of channels to join on boot...
        super().__init__(token='ACCESS_TOKEN', prefix='?', initial_channels=['...'])
```